# In Rails how can I implement a HTML select menu using an Array of Strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `FinancialDocument#document_type` model attribute. I'd like to let the user select the document type from an HTML select menu populated by an Array of Strings...

```
doctypes = [ 'Invoice', 'Packing slip', 'Other' ]
```

For each option, the displayed label and returned value would be identical.

I looked at the `select` and `collection_select` helpers, but they seem geared toward selecting a child model, not merely a String value. I couldn't discover how to bend them to my purpose.

Here's how I'm trying to do it (I'm using Haml, not Erb)...

```
form_for(@financial_document) do |f|
  - doctypes = [ 'Invoice', 'PS', 'Packing slip', 'Other' ]
  = f.collection_select @financial_document, :document_type, \
      doctypes, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true
```

I get this error...

```
undefined method `merge' for :to_s:Symbol
```

Is there a different helper that I could use for this? Or a way to use `select` or `collection_select`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is doctypes an ActiveRecord collection? Looking at the code it doesn't seems so.
You can use the `select` helper.

```
= f.select :document_type, doctypes, :include_blank => true
```

Also, you don't need to pass `@financial_document` if you call the tag on the form object created with form_for.

Answer (score 1):

```
doctypes.map!{|d| [d]}
f.select(@financial_document, :document_type, doctypes)
```

will do it I think.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me... undefined method `merge' for [["Invoice"], ["PS"], ["Packing slip"], ["Other"]]:Array